# Network call throws IO exception and connection refused in android not working in android device

Tags: android, http, network-protocols

I am trying to get the value from `Instagram` web server , In my code working fine in emulator but not working in android device.It's saying `IOException` and connection refused error.

I have given `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>` in `Manifest` file, 
the `URL` i have used is [https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/[here](https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/%5bhere) user id ]/?access_token=here access token

For network call i am using:

```
URL url = new URL(urls);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.connect();
String response = streamToString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
result = new JSONObject(response);`
```

`streamToString` is method:

```
private String streamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    String str = "";

    if (is != null) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            reader.close();
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        str = sb.toString();
    }
    return str;
}
```

my AsyncTask class

```
public class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> {

private Context context;
private Error error;
private RequestListener callback;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private String url;

public JSONParser(Context context, String url, RequestListener callback) {
    this.context = context;
    this.callback = callback;
    this.error = Error.UNKNOWN;
    this.url = url;
}
public JSONParser showProgressDialog(int messageId) {
    return showProgressDialog(null, context.getString(messageId));
}
public JSONParser showProgressDialog(String message) {
    return showProgressDialog(null, message);
}
public JSONParser showProgressDialog(int titleId, int messageId) {
    return showProgressDialog(context.getString(titleId), context.getString(messageId));
}
public JSONParser showProgressDialog(String title, String message) {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    if (title != null) {
        progressDialog.setTitle(title);
    }
    progressDialog.setMessage(message);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    return this;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    if (progressDialog != null) {
        progressDialog.show();
    }
}

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) {

    JSONObject result = null;
    if (isNetworkReachable()) {
        try {

            String urls = url;
            URL url = new URL(urls);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();
            String response = streamToString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            result = new JSONObject(response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ALog.e("IOException : %s", e.getMessage());
            error = Error.IO_ERROR;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            ALog.e("ParseException : %s", e.getMessage());
            error = Error.PARSE_ERROR;
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            ALog.e("JSONException : %s", e.getMessage());
            error = Error.PARSE_ERROR;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ALog.e("UnknownException : %s", e.getMessage());
            error = Error.UNKNOWN;
        }
    } else {
        error = Error.NETWORK_UNAVAILABLE;
    }
    return result;
}

private String streamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    String str = "";

    if (is != null) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is));
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            reader.close();
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        str = sb.toString();
    }
    return str;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    if (progressDialog != null) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
    if (!isCancelled()) {
        if (jsonObject != null) {
            callback.onRequestSuccess(jsonObject);
        } else {
            callback.onRequestFailure(error);
        }
    }
}
```

Only not working in device , it's working on emulator

Comment: JSONParser.doInBackground@77: IOException : and the same which i gave the link is here

Comment: @John please post full logcat, not only part of it

Comment: I think your are not using asynctask for getting data.That's why it is giving you the exception.also post your logcat

Comment: @nikis i got only above line and again i am pasting here JSONParser.doInBackground@77: IOException : https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/[here user id ]/?access_token=[here access token]

Comment: @TalhaQ i am using AsyncTask only its working on emulator but not in android device

Comment: @John no, it's not a full error, please take a look at the logcat carefully. Also post relevant code since `AsyncTask` is not listed in question

Comment: @nikis i have added my AsyncTask class pls check it now

Comment: @John ok, you get `IOException` thrown, what's the message is going wit it? you should see it' since you have `ALog.e("IOException : %s", e.getMessage());`

Comment: @nikis this what i get JSONParser.doInBackground@77: IOException : https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/13030778/?access_token=13030778.0f97f44.bc726077df0b4a5d836c1f561bfaa5

Comment: @nikis other then this i am not getting anything from my logcat

Comment: @John try to call `e.printStackTrace()` to see the full picture

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52312/discussion-between-john-and-nikis)

Comment: Just as a check to verify it is not a network provider issue, make sure you can hit the server from the device web browser

Comment: @ChrisStratton i open the link in mobile browser its open no issue

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking if the device has an active internet connection, then if true make the http connection. 
Like this:

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                      activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
if (isConnected) {
  URL url = new URL(urls);
  HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
  urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
  urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
  urlConnection.connect();

// more stuff here
}
```

Hope it helps.